# ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).switchMap is not a function at new AngularFireAuth

Tags: firebase, angular6, angularfire2, zonejs

My package.json

```
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
"@ngx-kit/core": "github:ngx-kit/core-builds#test+31e741a",
"angular-socialshare": "^2.3.11",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
"firebase": "4.8.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.9",
"ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
"ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
"typescript": "~2.9.2"  }
```

This project compiles successfully, but it throws an error in my broswer:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4baY.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please post your code and the error message here (not as an image).

Comment: this is the error ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).switchMap is not a function
    at new AngularFireAuth (auth.js:22)
    at _getAngularFireAuth (auth.module.js:6)
    at _callFactory (core.js:8433)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8389)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8349)
    at NgModuleRef_.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9057)
    at resolveDep (core.js:9422)
    at createClass (core.js:9302)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9179)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10399)

Comment: Please edit your original question with the code you have which throws the error and the message. It's difficult to read in comments, and without context it's impossible to debug.

Comment: @cano did you manage to work this one out at all, I have the same error now that I've upgraded a 5.2 project to 7

Comment: @dibs no , i delete everything from the original project and i restart from scratch !